# SiteSmashers - Reviewing Website designs?

Tags: discussion

So, a few times pals in the JS chat over at Stack Overflow have provided some really insightful comments on web designs I'm working on.  What i'm wondering is, can i ask questions like that here? I'm guessing *no* unless i provide actual code i want reviewed (versus "how does my site look, anything to change?").

And while i'm at it, does anyone think this would make a good SE site proposal?

And no, this isn't a [dupe](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/can-i-ask-for-a-review-on-a-website) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question that really hasn't come up. And there is that "Application UI" thing in the FAQ...

My gut feeling is no. Our site name is *Code* Review, and I think it was founded mainly for code, not UIs or web page designs (Supported by the fact that we don't have any). The site is for refining code, finding the most optimal and readable solution for a given problem. It seems to me that a web design would be defining a code problem, not refining an existing one.

I would suggest you take a look at https://ux.stackexchange.com/. Note: They do *not* do full designs. However, if you have [specific questions using an example](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/should-critique-requests-be-allowed-on-the-site), it should be ok. Break it down into individual elements, just like you would do for a large chunks of code here, and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks @Michael! naturally stupid and hot headed me already proposed a SE site... but i'll scratch that idea and go with UX.